# What is best practice to call wordpress media uploader (wp.media)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have more than 5 tabs in a metabox. In every metabox i have a bootstrap modal for image variations holding some inputs and a button with class of `.btn.select_media_` and a data-id attribute which holding unique ID of that tab. I am opening wp uploader on click of this button. please see my JS code.

```
var mediaUploader;
$(document).on('click','.btn.select_media_',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    // If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    console.log('clicked:'+id);
    if (mediaUploader) {
      mediaUploader.open();
      return;
    }
    // Extend the wp.media object
    mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
    ///mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.mediaUploader = wp.media({
      title: 'Choose Image',
      button: {
      text: 'Choose Image'
    }, multiple: false });

    mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
      attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
      $('#img_url_'+ id).val(attachment.url);
      $('#img_width_'+ id).val(attachment.width+'px');
      $('#img_title_'+ id).val(attachment.title);
      $('#show_img_'+ id).attr('src',attachment.url);
      console.log('selected'+ id);
    });
    // Open the uploader dialog
    mediaUploader.open();
});
```

Problem is that when i set/upload an image in any one tab this function run and set value of images in `mideaUploader.on('select')` event. when i am try to select image in an other tab i noticed in console that `console.log('selected'+ id);` had old value (on which tab i set first time) and `console.log('clicked'+ id);` had newer id value.

Please help!, what is wrong with my code? and how can i get same value at top and bottom of this handler?

Answer (score 0):

Its good i solved my problem by declaring a `global object` and assign `data-id` value to this object.